# How to use dotnet core 3 intrinsic StoreAlignedNonTemporal

Tags: c#, .net-core, sse

I'm trying to learn about the new dotnet core 3 intrinsics (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/ ).

I want to implement the simple c++ example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403779/1462295)

```cpp
#include "emmintrin.h"

const __m128i v2 = _mm_set1_epi64x(2);
__m128i v = _mm_set_epi64x(1, 0);

for (size_t i=0; i<1000*1000*1000; i += 2)
{
    _mm_stream_si128((__m128i *)&data[i], v);
    v = _mm_add_epi64(v, v2);
}
```

(I realize the above can previously be done in C# using SIMD `Vector`)

Looking at https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Runtime/Intrinsics/X86/Sse2.cs,1392 , I assume I need to use the function

```
/// <summary>
/// void _mm_stream_si128 (__m128i* mem_addr, __m128i a)
///   MOVNTDQ m128, xmm
/// </summary>
public static unsafe void StoreAlignedNonTemporal(long* address, Vector128<long> source) => StoreAlignedNonTemporal(address, source);
```

My C# program is as follows.

Intrinsics.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if(!Sse2.IsSupported){
                Console.WriteLine("Your CPU doesn't support SSE2 Instruction set");
                return;
            }

        var data = new long[100000];
        var v = Vector128.Create(1L, 0L);
        var v2 = Vector128.Create(0L, 0L);

        Span<long> buffer = data.AsSpan();

        for (int i=0; i<100000; i+=2)
        {
            Sse2.StoreAlignedNonTemporal(buffer[i], v);
            // TODO: convert this to C#: v = _mm_add_epi64(v, v2);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build the project, it fails with the following error:

```
burnsba@debian:~/code/Intrinsics$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.3.0+0f4c62fea for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Restore completed in 24.2 ms for /home/burnsba/code/Intrinsics/Intrinsics.csproj.
Program.cs(22,42): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'byte*' [/home/burnsba/code/Intrinsics/Intrinsics.csproj]
Program.cs(22,53): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector128<long>' to 'System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector128<byte>' [/home/burnsba/code/Intrinsics/Intrinsics.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Program.cs(22,42): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'long' to 'byte*' [/home/burnsba/code/Intrinsics/Intrinsics.csproj]
Program.cs(22,53): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector128<long>' to 'System.Runtime.Intrinsics.Vector128<byte>' [/home/burnsba/code/Intrinsics/Intrinsics.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.19

burnsba@debian:~/code/Intrinsics$ dotnet --version
3.0.100
```

How am I supposed to use `Sse2.StoreAlignedNonTemporal`?

Comment: `buffer[i]` is a `long`, not a `long*`. After that it's the compiler trying to find the best match and not being able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I got the program to compile and run with the following changes. In that sense, my question is answered.

Intrinsics.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.11.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86;
using System.Runtime.Intrinsics;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;

namespace IntrinsicsDemo
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!Sse2.IsSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your CPU doesn't support SSE2 Instruction set");
                return;
            }

            var summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<IntrinsicsBench>();
        }
    }

    [SimpleJob]
    [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public unsafe class IntrinsicsBench
    {
        private long[] _data = new long[100000];
        private Vector128<long> _v = Vector128.Create(1L, 0L);
        private Vector128<long> _v2 = Vector128.Create(0L, 0L);

        public IntrinsicsBench()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
            {
                _data[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
        public long[] Default()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
            {
                _data[i] = i;
            }

            return _data;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public long[] DefaultSpan()
        {
            var buffer = _data.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                buffer[i] = i;
            }

            return _data;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public long[] Unroll8()
        {
            var buffer = _data.AsSpan();
            for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += 8)
            {
                buffer[i + 0] = i + 0;
                buffer[i + 1] = i + 1;
                buffer[i + 2] = i + 2;
                buffer[i + 3] = i + 3;
                buffer[i + 4] = i + 4;
                buffer[i + 5] = i + 5;
                buffer[i + 6] = i + 6;
                buffer[i + 7] = i + 7;
            }

            return _data;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public long[] Sse2Test()
        {
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (long* lp = _data)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; i += 2)
                    {
                        Sse2.StoreAlignedNonTemporal(lp + i, _v);
                        _v = Sse2.Add(_v, _v2);
                    }
                }
            }

            return _data;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the method that uses the SSE2 intrinsics is more than twice as slow as the default naive implementation:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.11.5, OS=Windows 10.0.17763.805 (1809/October2018Update/Redstone5)
Intel Core i7-8850H CPU 2.60GHz (Coffee Lake), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=3.0.100
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.0.0 (CoreCLR 4.700.19.46205, CoreFX 4.700.19.46214), 64bit RyuJIT


|      Method |      Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
|------------ |----------:|----------:|----------:|------:|--------:|------:|------:|------:|----------:|
|     Default |  43.53 us | 0.8155 us | 0.8009 us |  1.00 |    0.00 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
| DefaultSpan |  43.51 us | 0.4265 us | 0.3562 us |  1.00 |    0.02 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|     Unroll8 |  32.81 us | 0.6404 us | 0.8327 us |  0.76 |    0.03 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
|    Sse2Test | 104.92 us | 2.0906 us | 2.5674 us |  2.41 |    0.08 |     - |     - |     - |         - |
```

Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: I think there's a problem with the logic above and/or something suboptimal with how Sse2.StoreAlignedNonTemporal is being used. Following along with  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/hardware-intrinsics-in-net-core/ , using SSE2 to sum all the elements in an array is significantly faster than the naive approach

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `long*` as an argument to `StoreAlignedNonTemporal` but you are supplying a `long`. The compiler is unable to find a matching method signature.

You can have a look at how it's used here: [coreclr/tests/src/JIT/HardwareIntrinsics/X86/Sse2/StoreAlignedNonTemporal.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/030a3ea9b8dbeae89c90d34441d4d9a1cf4a7de6/tests/src/JIT/HardwareIntrinsics/X86/Sse2/StoreAlignedNonTemporal.cs#L51)

> ```cs
> long* inArray = stackalloc long[2]; 
> byte* outBuffer = stackalloc byte[32]; 
> long* outArray = (long*)Align(outBuffer, 16);
>
> var vf = Unsafe.Read<Vector128<long>>(inArray);
> Sse2.StoreAlignedNonTemporal(outArray, vf);
> ```

Note that the use of intrinsics is only possible in `unsafe` code.